# strstr function and multi dimensional arrays in c

Tags: c, initialization, fgets, c-strings, strstr

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void find_track(char *search_for);
char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima"
};

int main() {
    char *to_search_str;
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(to_search_str, 80, stdin);
    find_track(to_search_str);
    return 0;
}

void find_track(char *search_for) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for)) {
            printf("Track %d: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The program is supposed to search for a string in every string in the `tracks` multi dimensional array but the `strstr()` function in the `find_track` is always returning null no matter the input (even if we input the a sub string of a string from `tracks` multi dimensional array). I don't know why this is happening?

**EDIT**:
After correction

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void find_track(char *search_for);
char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima"
};

int main() {
    char to_search_str[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(to_search_str, 80, stdin);
    to_search_str[strlen(to_search_str)-1] = '\0';
    find_track(to_search_str);
    return 0;
}

void find_track(char *search_for) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for)) {
            printf("Track %d: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: What does the sample input file look like? Please _edit_ your question and post a representative amount. After fixing the bugs that others have mentioned below, you may need to reverse the order of the args to `strstr`. For example, you'd need to do this to get a match if the input line was: `My favorite song is: "Dancing with a Dork" but I also like: "The girl from Iwo Jima" as well.`

Comment: I am just starting to learn C. The input i assume to give is just a single word like `Dancing` or 'Harvard'

Comment: @CraigEstey I do not have to reverse the order of args it works fine

Comment: That's fine. There are two types of search: (1) In a [long] input sentence, look for a match to one of the song lyric lines. (2) In a file that has a list of words, one per line, see which words are in a given song lyric. It wasn't clear from your question which was the desired result [because the sample input wasn't provided].

Comment: Your edited code is [still] incorrect. You are clipping one too many chars with `to_search_str[strlen(to_search_str)-2] = '\0';`--it should be only `-1`. As you have it, an input line of `Harvard` --> `Harvar`. Also, a line like `wonderfuls` --> `wonderful` and would match even though it shouldn't. Also, even with the `-1` fix, some input files leave off the final newline, so the code would chop the last line. A surer way to get rid of newline: `*strchrnul(to_search_str,'\n') = 0;` [this is similar to what Vlad suggested with `strcspn` but is faster]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the issue with input via `fgets()`.

- You are reading into an uninitialized pointer `to_search_str`, which does not point to a valid memory location. In this case, you can simply change this to an array, like `char to_search_str[80] = {0};` and get done with it.
- You need to trim the trailing newline that's stored in the input buffer.

  From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), (*emphasis mine*)

> *`fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an `EOF` or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.** A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last character in the buffer.*

A quick way of getting that done is `to_search_str[strcspn(to_search_str, "\n")] = 0;`, but there are more robust ways mentioned in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2173917)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't allocating `to_search_str` pointer, the `char *` pointer you pass to `fgets` as the destination buffer. Being it actually uninitialized, this causes undefined behavior that normally ends with a program crash.

You just need to allocate it, statically or dynamically.

The simplest solution consists in just defining a static array in the stack:

```
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 80

int main() {
    char to_search_str[LEN];

    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(to_search_str, LEN, stdin);

    /* Remove trailing newline from the string to search */
    to_search_str[strcspn(to_search_str, "\n")] = 0;

    find_track(to_search_str);
    return 0;
}
```

The size of the array is 80 because you use this number as the *size* parameter in `fgets`. Please note the use of a `#define` for the constant 80, making possible to change it in a easier way.

The dynamic allocation in the heap involves the use of `malloc()` function (and `free()` as soon as the array is not needed anymore):

```
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 80

int main() {
    char * to_search_str = malloc(LEN);

    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(to_search_str, LEN, stdin);

    /* Remove trailing newline from the string to search */
    to_search_str[strcspn(to_search_str, "\n")] = 0;

    find_track(to_search_str);

    free(to_search_str);
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** since `fgets` retains trailing newline ``\n'` in the output buffer, we have to remove it. I used the clever *oneliner* solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/11336762).

Comment: I'm _not_ your DVer, but two things. (1) I'd do (e.g.): `#define LEN 80` and then `char *to_search_str = malloc(LEN); fgets(to_search_str,LEN,stdin);` Or, just: `char to_search_str[80]; fgets(to_search_str,sizeof(to_search_str),stdin);` (2) But, the real issue may be that the code _needs_ to chop off the newline. IMO, DVing without explanation is not the way to go. Usually, a comment to allow the responder to fix is sufficient. Only if responder does _not_ fix an _egregiously_ wrong answer, should DV be used.

Comment: @CraigEstey thanks for your comment. I can sure add the `#define LEN 80`; I would use it in my actual code but I didn't include it in my answer. I'm not sure about the trailing newline issue as: 1) there's no mention in the question about this requirement (one could actually want to retain it) - 2) OP's test syrings don't contain a newline.

Comment: @CraigEstey I added also a note about getting rid of the trailing newline.

Comment: Strip of newline _is_ required. If you run a corrected [e.g. your] version that does _not_ have a newline strip, the search will fail for a prompted string of `Harvard\n`. With strip, the `to_search_for` string will be `Harvard` which _will_ succeed.

Comment: I used another way of getting rid of the newline is it the correct way? `to_search_str[strlen(to_search_str)-1] = '\0';`

Comment: I think you have to do  `to_search_str[strcspn(to_search_str, "\n")] = '\0';`  to remove the trailing new line.

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, of course you are right...^_^ it seems that yesyerday I wasn't able to write an accurate answer...

Comment: @Anonymous `to_search_str[strlen(to_search_str)-1] = '\0';` is wrong because in case you have an empty string you write at index -1, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Thanks for clarification from now on i make sure to never uses that method for removing the newline character

Answer (score 0):

`char *to_search_str;` is an uninitialized pointer, writing to it will result in undefined behavior. You have to allocate memory or use an array instead `char to_search_str[100];` for example.

Also don't forget that `fgets` will also read the newline into the buffer, which you have to remove.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet in main

```
char *to_search_str;
printf("Search for: ");
fgets(to_search_str, 80, stdin);
```

invokes undefined behavior because the pointer `to_search_str` is not initialized and has indeterminate value.

It seems you at least mean

```
char to_search_str[80];
printf("Search for: ");
fgets(to_search_str, 80, stdin);
```

The function `fgets` can append the new line character `'\n'` to the entered string.

You need to remove it for example the following way

```
to_search_str[ strcspn( to_search_str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

The function `find_track` should be declared at least like

```
void find_track( const char *search_for);
```

Though it is a bad idea when a function definition relies on global variables.

Also the approach of finding relevant strings is not good. For example the user can enter a string that contains only one character `'a'`.  In this case all records will satisfy the condition. You should check that the searched string forms a word (a sequence of characters separated by spaces) in a string in the array.